# BatchScript: Playing Music in the Background, but stop once the program has been exited

Tags: batch-file, background-music

```
set "file=mfx\reboot.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
echo Sound.Controls.play
echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo wscript.sleep 100
echo loop
echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000)>soundctrl.vbs
cscript soundctrl.vbs
echo Working...
pause>nul
```

I've searched quite extensively for an answer to this question, and I hope that it is possible. I've managed to get music to play when the program is run, however, in previous versions where the `cscript` command was not used, and instead, I would use `start soundctrl.vbs` it would play in the background, and continue with the program without a problem, but once the program closed it would continue to play, and I would have to end the `wscript` task in task manager.

Using the `cscript` command it does what I want perfectly, however, it does not continue past the `cscript` command onto where you see "Working...". I've considered `taskkill`, but I would have to direct the user to an exit command.

Or perhaps, I've been going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the funny you can try this code :

```bat
@echo off
Mode 64,35 & color 0A
Title Play Music 
Call :Play "http://www.chocradios.ch/djbuzzradio_windows.mp3.asx"
:::
:::      __   __  _______  ___      ___      _______
:::     |  | |  ||       ||   |    |   |    |       |
:::     |  |_|  ||    ___||   |    |   |    |   _   |
:::     |       ||   |___ |   |    |   |    |  | |  |
:::     |       ||    ___||   |___ |   |___ |  |_|  |
:::     |   _   ||   |___ |       ||       ||       |
:::     |__| |__||_______||_______||_______||_______|
:::
:::              _ _,---._
:::           ,-','       `-.___
:::          /-;'               `._
:::         /\/          ._   _,'o \
:::        ( /\       _,--'\,','"`. )
:::         |\      ,'o     \'    //\
:::         |      \        /   ,--'""`-.
:::         :       \_    _/ ,-'         `-._
:::          \        `--'  /                )
:::           `.  \`._    ,'     ________,','
:::             .--`     ,'  ,--` __\___,;'
:::              \`.,-- ,' ,`_)--'  /`.,'
:::               \( ;  | | )      (`-/
:::                 `--'| |)       |-/
:::                   | | |        | |
:::                   | | |,.,-.   | |_
:::                   | `./ /   )---`  )
:::                  _|  /    ,',   ,-'
:::                 ,'|_(    /-<._,' |--,
:::                 |    `--'---.     \/ \
:::                 |          / \    /\  \
:::               ,-^---._     |  \  /  \  \
:::            ,-'        \----'   \/    \--`.
:::           /            \              \   \
:::
::**************************************************************
for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do @echo(%%A
pause>nul & exit
::**************************************************************
:Play
(
echo Play "%~1"
echo Sub Play(URL^)
echo    Dim Sound
echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo    Sound.URL = URL
echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo    Sound.Controls.play
echo    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo        wscript.sleep 100
echo    loop
echo    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
echo End Sub
)>"%Temp%\%~n0.vbs"
start "Play Music" /Min cscript.exe //nologo "%Temp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::**************************************************************
```

Comment: Very nice ASCII. ^-^

Answer (score 0):

In order to continue running your script without waiting for cscript to return, you'll need to start a separate process.

```
start "Music" /Min cscript.exe soundctrl.vbs
```

Comment: Yes, that was one of the things I was considering if it couldn't be entirely done. Well, I suppose this is as close as I can get to it. Thank you for taking the time to help.